# What has I done? If-statement working....somewhat

Tags: c

So last night I asked a question about a trig calculator I'm trying to make for practice and I'm back again with question that's pretty related to my last question. Ive sort of fixed the calculator since last night, but for some odd reason one of the if-statements is passing the test given for a different if-statement. Here is the code I have-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int x;
float o, h, a, S, C, T;
enum { sine, cosine, tangent};

printf("Enter the value for the function you wish to calculate\n(Sine = 0 Cosine = 1  Tangent = 2): ");
scanf("%f", &x);

if(x == 0)
{
    printf("Enter the value of the opposite leg: ");
    scanf("%f", &o);
    printf("Enter the value of the hypotenuse: ");
    scanf("%f", &h);

    S = o / h;
    printf("The sine is equal to %f", S);
}

else if(x < 2, x > 0)
{
    printf("Enter the value of the adjacent leg: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter the value of the hypotenuse: ");
    scanf("%f", &h);

    C = a / h;
    printf("The cosine is equal to %f", C);
}

else if(x == 2)
{
    printf("Enter the value of the opposite leg: ");
    scanf("%f", &o);
    printf("Enter the value of the adjacent leg");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    T = o / a;
    printf("The tangent is equal to %f", T);
}
else
{
    printf("Wat da fack");
}

return 0;


}
```

What happens is the cosine test passes for the tangent and the tangent function doesn't work. As before, I'm still pretty new to this so go easy on me..  Btw, the reason that I have two test conditions for cosine is that it wouldn't run unless i had it like that, sny insight into that is appreciated too.

Comment: What is `x < 2, x > 0`? Did you mean `x < 2 && x > 0`? Also, since `x` is an integer, why don't you just check if `x == 1`?

Comment: Also, why don't you read up on logic operations? What makes you think that the compiler knows what you assume?

Comment: i've tried just setting it to look for 1. When I do, it just skips to "wat da fack"

Comment: besides the problem in with the comma separated conditions that others have noted, your problem is probably the `scanf` function, as in your previous question. This is relatively tricky for beginners. You should try to fix your logic of the program first without it, just by assigning values to your variables. In any case your code clearly shows that you'd first have to read up much more on control structures in C. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

`if (x < 2, x > 0)` does not do what you think. It should be `if (x<2 && x>0)`; read about the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in *C*

And if you compiled with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) you would probably have gotten a warning. And you should learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).

The compiler (at least GCC) should warn you against `scanf("%f", &x);` where `x` is some `int`. You probably want `scanf (" %d", &x);` and you may want to test the result of `scanf` (it gives you the number of successfully read elements).

You very probably need to end every `printf` format string with a newline (e.g. code `printf("Enter the value of the opposite leg:\n");` for example) -or else call `fflush` very often- and you'll better put a space in your `scanf` format string like `scanf(" %f", &a)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does `x < 2, x > 0` do?

Comment: It computes `x < 2`, then throws the result away and computes `x > 0`. It's basically the same as `x > 0` in this context.

Comment: @Blender The comma operator evaluates to the last expression in the list, i. e. it evaluates `x < 2` and `x > 0` then it returns the value of `x > 0`.

Comment: Thanks, I already learned something new in under a minute.

Comment: @AprilMeiddie: learn also to enable warnings in your compiler, get the habit of improving the code till no warnings are given, and learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: I have warnings enabled, sometimes the seem too general to be of much use though.

Comment: No, you should trust the compiler. Take the habit of improving your code till no warnings are given.

Answer (score 2):

In `scanf("%f", &x);`, replace `%f` by `%d` because `x` is an `int`, but this is not the major problem,

Problem is in `if` statement condition,

`comma(,)` is not used for `AND` purpose, you have to use `&&`,,so your state become,

```
if ((x < 2) && (x > 0))
```

**EDIT**

please replace `%f` with `%d` in `scanf` when you are taking `x` from user...

`scanf("%d", &x);` this will solve your problem.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the problem with `scanf()`.FYI, it's actually UB.

Comment: Thanks, that stopped tangent from passing the test, but tangent is still just skipping over when i enter "2" and going to the else statement

Comment: Hey, wanna know something really weird? I switched it to %d and then cosine started to not work. I switched it back to %f and now the whole thing is working perfectly. So, thanks i guess?

Comment: `%d` is working for me..

Comment: You do want %f for when you are reading floating point values, %d when you read integer values. x is an integer, the sidees of triangles and the resulting trig function values are float values. Again, gcc will warn for "format string not matching inputs".

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, the problem seems to be in your second `else if()` statement. Basically what is happing there is that both statements `x < 2` and `x > 0` are executed but only `x > 0` is being used to test the condition. So the test for the cosine function will also pass for the tangent function i.e `cosine > 0` , `tangent > 0` and the test for the tangent function will never be executed.

A better way to perform the comparison there would be to use just test if `x == 1` or you can use `else if(x > 0 && x < 2)`